# How to check all artifacts in Artifactory if their files exist on disk?

Tags: artifactory

We are running a local installation of Artifactory Pro which contains around 1M artifacts. Recently, we tried to migrate from the embedded Derby DB to Postgres and switched back to Derby because of errors occurring during the migration.

After that, users reported missing files, mostly maven-metadata.xml but also at least one pom.xml. The files are missing on the filesystem.

The only way I can think of is to query the Artifactory API for all files, try to download them and check if they can be downloaded. Is there a better way to check all artifacts in Artifactory if they exist on the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, Thomas!

Although that kind of errors don't happen in normal operation, data migration back and forth of a large number of artifacts can lead to those problems sometimes.

We have [a user plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/filestore/filestoreIntegrity) find them, so check it out, looks like it is exactly what you need.

Comment: thanks a lot, the user plugin did work as expected and found a lot of maven-metadata.xml which are missing on disk and also files which are only on disk but not know to Artifactory. I'll investigate what those files are and if they maybe are the ones Artifactory claims to be missing